# rassigning variables in python when they do and dont

Tags: python, variables, input

I am confused as to when variables get reassigned in my code and when they remain constant. I have used print statements to narrow down which custom function is causing the problem I just can't find the line. I'm trying to make a store in Python using more or less beginner code.

```
def buy(vx, vy, p, cash,price):
if cash >= price:
    if (box_range(vx, vy, 670, 960, 430, 540) and p == 1)and len(shopping_list)>= 1:
        for i in range(0, len(shopping_list)):
            my_items.append(shopping_list[i])
        print "The computer appended " + str(len(shopping_list)) + " items."
        print "my items are now " + str(my_items)
        cash -= price
        if p == 1:
            print "balance is " + str(cash)
        return cash
elif cash < price and (box_range(vx, vy, 670, 960, 430, 540) and p == 1)and len(shopping_list)>= 1:
    print "you don't have enough money"
    return cash
else:
    return cash
```

The vx and vy variables relate to the position of the mouse, p refers to whether or not the mouse was pressed, assume price is 0, shopping list is a list of classes, my items is a list of classes and the value of cash imputed into the function is 1000, however, sometimes it returns None and I can't figure out why.

Comment: can you post the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that the inner `if` returns `cash-price` if the condition is satisfied but it returns nothing (meaning `None`) when the condition `(box_range(vx, vy, 670, 960, 430, 540) and p == 1) and len(shopping_list)>= 1` **is not satisfied**:

```
if cash >= price:
    if (box_range(vx, vy, 670, 960, 430, 540) and p == 1)and len(shopping_list)>= 1:
        for i in range(0, len(shopping_list)):
            my_items.append(shopping_list[i])
        print "The computer appended " + str(len(shopping_list)) + " items."
        print "my items are now " + str(my_items)
        cash -= price
        if p == 1:
            print "balance is " + str(cash)
        return cash
    else: # what should be returned when, e.g., len(shopping_list) < 1???
        return SOMETHING
elif ...
```

Specify the value to be returned when the condition `(box_range(vx, vy, 670, 960, 430, 540) and p == 1) and len(shopping_list)>= 1` is not satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that really helps and saves me countless hours, I would give you an upvote but I don't have a good enough reputation yet

Comment: @ChrisHowe You are welcome. Even though you may not be able to up-vote an answer, I think you should be able to accept it.